# Range Extension Issue with Macro StartPoint

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a code that helps extend chart by a certain range given what is put in the Input box.  However, I'm looking to change it so now that instead of the EndPoint being extended by Rng_Extension it is the StartPoint now. However, when I change it there is an error at the

`ser.Values = StartPoint & ":" & EndPoint`

and at the

`ser.XValues = StartPoint & ":" & EndPoint`

part as it can't combine the two for some reason. Can anyone help?

```
  Sub Chart_Extender()
  Dim Rng_Extension As Integer
  Dim Series_Formula As String
  Dim StartPoint As String
  Dim EndPoint As String
  Dim CommaSplit As Variant
  Dim ColonSplit As Variant
  Dim grph As ChartObject
  Dim ser As Series

    On Error GoTo BadEntry
      Rng_Extension = InputBox( _
  "How many cells do you want to extend your chart's series?", _
  "Chart Extender")
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each grph In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
      For Each ser In grph.Chart.SeriesCollection

  If ser.NAME = "ACTUALS" Then
  Exit For
  End If

    If ser.ChartType <> 75 Then
      'Get range of series
        Series_Formula = ser.Formula

      'X Axis Values
        CommaSplit = Split(Series_Formula, ",") 'Delimit by comma

        ColonSplit = Split(CommaSplit(2), ":")  'Delimit 3rd part by colon

        StartPoint = ColonSplit(0)  'Starting Point of Range

        EndPoint = ColonSplit(1)    'Current Ending Point Range

        EndPoint = Range(EndPoint).Offset(0, Rng_Extension).Address 'Extended Ending Point Range

        ser.Values = StartPoint & ":" & EndPoint 'Combine Start and End Point & Set Series = To It

      'X Axis Labels
        If CommaSplit(1) <> "" Then
          ColonSplit = Split(CommaSplit(1), ":")  'Delimit 3rd part by colon

          StartPoint = ColonSplit(0)  'Starting Point of Range

          EndPoint = ColonSplit(1)    'Current Ending Point Range

          EndPoint = Range(EndPoint).Offset(0, Rng_Extension).Address  'Extended Ending Point Range

          ser.XValues = StartPoint & ":" & EndPoint 'Combine Start and End Point & Set Series = To It
        End If
    End If
     Next ser
     Next grph

  'Completion Message
MsgBox "Your chart has been Extended by " & Rng_Extension & " positions."

  Exit Sub

  'Error Handling
  BadEntry:
    MsgBox "Your input must be a whole number, aborting", vbCritical,       "Improper Entry"

  End Sub
```

Comment: After `EndPoint = Range(EndPoint).Offset...`, on the next line put `Debug.Print "StartPoint = " & StartPoint & CHR(10) & "EndPoint = " & EndPoint`. Put a break on the line `ser.Value = ....` and run your code. The intermediate window will show you Start and End points. Are they what you expect?

Comment: @Tyeler Yes the Values are what I'd expect them to be. For example if I change 

EndPoint = Range(EndtPoint).Offset(0, Rng_Extension).Address to StartPoint = Range(StartPoint).Offset(0, Rng_Extension).Address the ser.Values line breaks and won't combine them and return them to the Series_Formula. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, I don't know a whole lot about `Series`, but from what the [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197014.aspx) says, it looks like you might want to try changing it to `ser.Values = ActiveSheet.Range(StartPoint & ":" & EndPoint)`. Did I read that right?

Comment: @Tyeler
This worked actually! Thank you very much!

Comment: We both learned something new! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

simple and gets the work done. thank you guys!
just a tip:
EndPoint = Range(EndPoint).Offset(0, Rng_Extension).Address adds COLUMNS of new data, whereas 
EndPoint = Range(EndPoint).Offset(Rng_Extension, 0).Address adds ROWS of new data